# How to get a call stack from a SoftWare Interrupt exception

Tags: gdb, arm, bare-metal

I'm trying to debug a program running on a **bare-metal** ARM platform using `gdb`. At some point an `SWI` (Software Interrupt) exception is generated. However the back-trace doesn't show what generated the exception as you can see:

> (gdb) c
>
> ```
> Continuing. 
> ^C 
> Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. 0xffff0008 in ?? ()
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0xffff0008 in ?? ()
> ```

The program running on the ARM was compiled with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -c -ggdb`, I also tried using `-O0` with the same result.

How can I get a meaningful call stack? Is there another way to find what is generating this exception?

Comment: Can you print the registers?  Also, is this *bare metal* or do you have an OS?

Comment: I can print the registers, but the program counter is 0xffff0008, which information in the registers should I try to analyze? Actually after setting some breakpoints and stepping in the assembly instructions I was able to see that my code is branching to a memory address past my program, which contains undefined instructions, leading to the SWI exception. This is bare metal, without OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the issue `gdb` has with producing a stack trace, you first have to understand how `gdb` produces a stack trace.   A compiler use a standard *prologue* and *epilogue* when it creates a `C` function, this is *assembler* code at function entry and exit.  Part of this is to save the `lr` on the stack, reserve space for local variables **and** link the previous *frame pointer* or `fp`.  These *stack frames* provide a type of linked list that is *root-ed* with the `fp` and normally terminated with *zero*.  This depends on the **ABI** (see [*-mabi*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html)).  The specifics are slightly different for each ARM [**ABI**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0036b/index.html) type, but the concepts are similar.

So, when the `SWI` (or any exception happens), it completely interrupts the flow of the `C` compiled code and the *frame pointer* list can be difficult to decode, especially in the case of a stack corruption.  Also, `gdb` does not decode the context of the program.  Some systems may change the frame pointer and immediately switch from an `exception mode` to `system/supervisor mode`.  The `sp` of the exception may even be used as a scratch register.  When the `SWI` is entered, part of the job of the handler will be to save the `user` registers (`r0-r12`).  In the case of a *multi-tasking O/S*, this may result in a complete change of the `user` stack, from one task to another.

You can always determine the *faulting/causing* instruction by examining the `lr` in the exception mode.  This specified in the [**ARM Architechure**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/), and is the same for any **ARM** CPU. `0xfff0008` is the default `SWI` handler address (when using a high memory vector table). Excepts from the `SWI` in the **ARM ARM (architechure reference manual)** follows,

---

**A2.6.4 Software Interrupt exception**

> The Software Interrupt instruction (SWI) enters Supervisor mode to request a particular supervisor (operating system) function. When a SWI is executed, the following actions are performed:

```
   R14_svc    = address of next instruction after the SWI instruction
   SPSR_svc   = CPSR
   CPSR[4:0]  = 0b10011                 /* Enter Supervisor mode */
   CPSR[5]    = 0                       /* Execute in ARM state */
                                        /* CPSR[6] is unchanged */
   CPSR[7]    = 1                       /* Disable normal interrupts */
                                        /* CPSR[8] is unchanged */
   CPSR[9]    = CP15_reg1_EEbit         /* Endianness on exception entry */
   if high vectors configured then
       PC     = 0xFFFF0008
   else
       PC     = 0x00000008
```

> To return after performing the SWI operation, use the following instruction to restore the PC (from R14_svc) and CPSR (from SPSR_svc) and return to the instruction following the SWI:

```
       MOVS PC,R14
```

---

As you can see, `R14_svc` which is the `lr` when in supervisor mode, is set to the `SWI` instruction+4.  This is so that the normal return will restart the following instruction.  By examining where the `lr` is, you can determine where the `SWI` occurred.  If the user stack is not corrupted, you can link your `supervisor` stack to the `user` stack using the *ABI* the compiler is using via the `fp`.  If you do this, then `gdb` can give a stack trace.  However, in the system under discussion, there is no `SWI` support code.

You could also write `gdb` macros to give a stack trace in this situation.  However, I hope it is clear that `gdb` would have a difficult task to do this generically.

Comment: It often happens to me that I get a SWI where PC=0xFFFF0008 and LR=0xFFFF0008 too, is there any way to know the last line executed in this situation?

Comment: I would examine what mode you were in.  Check the SPSR_svc and the user/modes `LR`.  Is it possible that you execute an `SWI` from the **SWI handler**.  You mean the CSPR says 'super' mode and the `PC` and `LR` are both 0xFFFF0008?  There are shadowed `LR` for other modes, but you can only see them if you switch the mode.  You maybe able to do this with a JTAG debugger.  I guess that is what you are using.  The *user* `LR` would tell you approximately where you where.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I meant after the SWI has occured and the ARM is in supervisor mode, with LR and SWI to 0xffff0008. Thank you again for the answer, I didn't know it was possible to change the ARM mode with the JTAG debugger. With gdb "set $cpsr=0xd0" does it, and then I can see the user LR.